# MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

Tags: python, dataframe, null, targetnullvalue, isnan

i am a little bit lost ...because i have this error and can not go ahead.
i supposed the reason will be the below resul of my table that include some math indicator i have tri to calculate.

```
null_values=data.isna().sum()
print(null_values)
```

output from the above code line:
future_returns                      1
signal                              0
pct_change                          1
pct_change2                         2
pct_change5                         5
rsi                                14
adx                                27
wma                                29
sma2                               49
sma                                49
corr                               54
volatility                          6
volatility2                        13

thanks for the help.

mrs. banditas.

Comment: for more explanation. i do not have on my data frame nan values, but i have a lot of this nan value, after the creation of some maths formula. why?how can i resolve?

Comment: please provide a sample of dataframe.

Comment: @clegane the original dataframe or the dataframe created and integrated with the maths formula, (in wich last i have the error)?